# Pandas: Read/Write CSV File that has Different Delimiters for Different Rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a student learning python, and i am running into some difficulties. I am trying to read a csv file that has different delimiters for different rows: Example:

```
Format:V1.1
Model: R
Step Size: 10mm
Distance: 10cm
Gain: 1000

X,Y
1,3
2,5
6,5
5,7
```

For the `X,Y` data, I have no problem getting it into the right cells, however I cannot separate the values after the colon for the first few rows. Its either one or the other. I am using pandas to read my `CSV` file. So far I have:

```
d=pd.read_csv('read.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=0)
```

When I replace the delimiter for `:`, it no longer works, and if i put sep=`,|:` it does not work either. In the end I need to plot the `x,y` values and i will need some of the info in the rows above like the gain to manipulate the y data. If you have any tips for me I would be very grateful!

Thanks

Comment: hmmm, why need one dataframe with 2 different sets of data?

Comment: Please add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , because `sep=',|:'` working for your sample data.